# scroll to bottom works when i scroll to top

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the code below to alert a message when scrolled to the bottom of the page.
It alerts when i scroll to the top of the page.

what went wrong?

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

        if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height()-$(window).height()){

            alert("BOTTOM");
                }
});
```

Comment: This seems to work... can you provide an image?  Take a [look...](http://jsfiddle.net/DXSfw/)

Comment: I just tried it and it works fine for me...

Comment: now it worked!! thanks. <!DOCTYPE html> was missing in the file

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1000);
```